# Xcode/Swift: animation strange jumps

Tags: swift, xcode, animation

I am having some strange problem with an animation in Swift. When I *only* do the animation, everything works fine. But when I add another change, for example a text at the same time, the animation suddenly jumps.

Pressing button 1: no problem

Pressing button 2: suddenly the animation is totally wrong. WHY?

I cannot figure out why this happens, and what to do about it. The project can be downloaded from my website: http://maartenm.nl/AnimationProblem.zip

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {



@IBOutlet weak var problemtxt: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var block: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var buttontwo: UIButton!



@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(Double(2.0), animations:
        {
            self.block.center = CGPointMake(self.block.center.x + 280 , self.block.center.y)
        }
        , completion: { (Bool)  in
            self.block.center = CGPointMake(self.block.center.x - 280 , self.block.center.y)
    } )
}



@IBAction func buttonTwoPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    self.problemtxt.text = "now what happens?"
    UIView.animateWithDuration(Double(2.0), animations:
        {
            self.block.center = CGPointMake(self.block.center.x + 280 , self.block.center.y)
        }
        , completion: { (Bool)  in
            self.block.center = CGPointMake(self.block.center.x - 280 , self.block.center.y)               
    } )
}
```

}

Comment: As you're using autolayout you should be animating the constraints of your block, rather than the centre.

Comment: then a) Why does it work in Button1? and b) How do I animate constraints?

Comment: and c) What has the text-change to do with the animation?? It is outside the 'animateWithDuration' command!

Comment: Because when you update the label text, your view constraints are recalculated. This is interfering with your frame animation. Search for how to animate NSLayoutConstraints.

Comment: I'm sorry, but thats not it. I tried to remake the whole scene without constraints, but the moment I start animating, every image jumps around the screen, unwanted.